# Accessing elements in an array in JavaScript (array returned from PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, google-maps

I am currently working on a project that pulls data from the Google Maps API in a JQuery call, processes it in PHP and then will eventually display the results in a map. I am currently able to get the elements from the API call into an array and send the array back, but I'm not sure how to access the specific array in my JavaScript again. For reference, the first subarray is the longitude and latitude of the searched location, and the remaining subarrays are the longitude, latitude, and name of the destinations around the searched location. I was wondering if any of you know how I could access these elements (or maybe a different way to send them back from PHP in a more accessible way). My javascript call is:

```
    function getPlace() {
    var address1 = $("#address1").val();
    var city1 = $("#city1").val();
    var state1 = $("#state1").val();
    var type = $("#placesList").val();
    var lat; var long;
     $.ajax({
        url: 'findPlace.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {address1: address1, city1: city1, state1: state1, type: type},
        success: function(stuff) {
            var info = JSON.parse(stuff);
            lat = info.lat;
            long = info[0].long;
            var name = info.first();
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        } 
    });
}
```

And my PHP code (findPlace.php) is this:

```
 <?php
$type = $_GET["type"];
$address1 = $_GET["address1"];
$city1 = $_GET["city1"];
$state1 = $_GET["state1"];

$key = "AIzaSyBubKVVsy-AjrJoS57GWMskC8vkr3xsj0g";

// Find the location
$niceStreet = str_replace(" ", "+", $address1);
$niceCity = str_replace(" ","+", $city1);
$niceState = str_replace(" ","+", $state1);
$address = $niceStreet.",+".$niceCity.",+".$niceState;

$jsonURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$address."&key=".$key;
$json = file_get_contents($jsonURL);
$decodedJSON = json_decode($json, true);

$lat = $decodedJSON["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
$long = $decodedJSON["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];


// Find the places
$placeURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=".$lat.",".$long."&radius=1000&type=".$type."&key=".$key;
$placeJSON = file_get_contents($placeURL);

$decodedPlace = json_decode($placeJSON, true);

$place = $decodedPlace["results"][0]["name"];
$size = count($decodedPlace["results"]);

$results[0]["lat"] = $lat;
$results[0]["long"] = $long;
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
    $c = $i - 1;
    $results[$i]["lat"] = $decodedPlace["results"][$c]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
    $results[$i]["long"] = $decodedPlace["results"][$c]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
    $results[$i]["name"] = $decodedPlace["results"][$c]["name"];
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

As you can see I am trying to access the different variables in a few different arrays, but they all return the entire array returned by the PHP, rather than the value itself. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the timestamps, I found the answer to this question pretty quickly. I just accessed it using code like`var name = info[1]["name"];` I was using this method before, but I guess I just had syntax errors.